# MVVM Persistence from view model

Tags: mvvm, persistence

I'm new to MVVM, I get the general idea, but there's one thing that I've been having a tough time finding an answer for.  Inevitably an application will have a save button in the UI.  The UI talks to the View Model, the view model updates the model objects, and then the model saves to whatever persistence medium (DB, File System, Web Service...).

My question is how does this last step happen?  Does the View Model get an instance of a DAL object?

`public MyVm(IMyModel obj, IDal<IMyModel> dal){ ... }`

Or does `IMyModel` have CRUD methods as part of its interface.

Is it the third option, which is me getting this completely wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple [explanation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792(v=vs.110).aspx) with code sample of how it is done in C#, persistence medium is the context object. View model is used mainly to update some properties of the model object, then during "SaveOrUpdate" operation persistence medium should check wether the model has been modified somewhere else and wether the model state is valid (foreign key constraints, value constraints and so on). If there are none - the storage gets updated

Comment: Thank you.  I'll be using a interface instead of direct;y passing the db context object as I will be using multiple persistence methods, based on setup and environment, but this give me what I need.  I'll pass my persistence interface to my view models and update data that way This was what I was leaning towards, but wasn't completely certain if this was right.

Comment: @Jesse wouldn't it be a good idea to separate models from logic? Your models are simple POCO-objects and separate layer of services/repositories is responsible for CRUD operations?

Comment: They are separate.  I was just saying that the CRUD objects will implement an interface, because based on configuration implementation will differ, but the interface will remain the same.

Comment: @papadoble151 No, separating logic from business models is a terrible idea; its the anemic domain model antipattern.